# How to draw from point in one SVG element to point in another?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a situation where there are multiple SVG elements in an HTML document. The elements are laid out using HTML rules, box model, flexbox, and now I'm told grid will start being used soon.  This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Victoria1984/bp2kmtg8/) is an example, showing a pair of filled parabolas drawn with common endpoints and slightly different control points using a Quadratic path operation. Other cases may be simple horizontal or diagonal lines of various thickness.

In the first SVG in the fiddle, the two endpoints are in the same SVG block, and dimensions (in SVG units) are well known, and it is straightforward to draw the parabola. (the control points are also shown here)

However, the next two SVG demonstrate the problem. The endpoints are in separate SVGs, separated by unknown amounts of "stuff" here represented by a bit of text.  It is clear that javascript will be required to rewrite the coordinates of the endpoints and control points, so that the parabola (or whatever) can connect the two.

How do I obtain the SVG unit coordinates of the endpoint in the second SVG relative to the coordinate system of the third SVG, so that I can connect the parabola to its left endpoint?

One possibly simplifying assumption can be made: the SVG unit to pixel coordinate ratio will be consistent for any drawing, although for added complexity that ratio may change from time to time (triggering the need to recalculate and re-draw the cross-SVG items).

A possibly complicating issue is that most of the endpoints will be nested in two layers of nested SVG elements: the outer SVG will have its SVG unit be the same size as the CSS pixel, but the inner SVG will have this different unit size that may change from time to time.

IDs or CLASSes can be added as necessary to the solution.

```css
/**CSS*/

svg { overflow: visible; }
```

```html
<!--HTML -->

<svg width="12cm" height="6cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 600"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <title>Example quad01 - quadratic Bézier commands in path data</title>
  <desc>Picture showing a "Q" a "T" command,
        along with annotations showing the control points
        and end points</desc>
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="1198" height="598"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1" />

  <path d="M500,300 Q300,50 100,300 Q300,75 500,300"
        fill="green" stroke="green" stroke-width="1" />
  <!-- End points -->
  <g fill="black" >
    <circle cx="100" cy="300" r="3"/>
    <circle cx="500" cy="300" r="3"/>
  </g>
  <!-- Control points and lines from end points to control points -->
  <g fill="#888888" >
    <circle cx="300" cy="50" r="3"/>
    <circle cx="300" cy="75" r="3"/>
  </g>
  <path d="M100,300 L300,50 L500,300 
           L300,75 L100,300"
        fill="none" stroke="#888888" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
<br>

<svg width="2cm" height="6cm" viewBox="0 0 200 600"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <title>Example quad01 - quadratic Bézier commands in path data</title>
  <desc>SVG left endpoint</desc>
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="198" height="598"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1" />

  <!-- End points -->
  <g fill="black" >
    <circle cx="100" cy="300" r="3"/>
  </g>
</svg>
some stuff here
<svg width="2cm" height="6cm" viewBox="0 0 200 600"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <title>Example quad01 - quadratic Bézier commands in path data</title>
  <desc>SVG right endpoint</desc>
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="198" height="598"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1" />

  <path d="M100,300 Q-100,50 -300,300 Q-100,75 100,300"
        fill="green" stroke="green" stroke-width="1" />
  <!-- End points -->
  <g fill="black" >
    <circle cx="100" cy="300" r="3"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

(In general, the coordinates will not have the same Y position, this example is simplistic: but all I need is a way to determine the position of the endpoint in the proper coordinate system.)

Comment: Have a single root SVG, including a foreignObject for the stuff. (However Internet Explorer has problems with the  foreignObject.)

Comment: @FrancisHemsher If it were as simple as I've made the example, that'd be a great idea. But there are a lot of layout features in HTML/CSS that are not in SVG, so it would be a huge job, and huge changes to existing code that generates the layout, to embed it all in a root SVG. We don't much care about IE, though, so that is not a problem for your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was hard for me to figure out, but a co-worker helped, and we finally puzzled through it. The solution turns out to be fairly straightforward.

The way we puzzled things out, it seems that there is a coordinate transformation matrix that can be used to convert from SVG user coordinates to browser pixels... and, via its inverse, back to SVG user coordinates. This is obtained for each starting and ending elements by:

```
start = document.getElementById('startSVGElement');
spt = start.createSVGPoint();
sCTM = start.getScreenCTM();

end = document.getElementById('endSVGElement');
ept = end.createSVGPoint();
eCTM = end.getScreenCTM();
```

Then, to draw from a point ( 100, 400 ) in the starting element, to a point ( 50, 60 ) in the ending element, you fill in the points:

```
spt.x = 100;
spt.y = 400;
ept.x = 50;
ept.y = 60;
```

Now the transformation magic: transform the ending point from SVG space to browser pixel space based on its CTM, and then transform back to SVG space using the starting element CTM inverse:

```
ept_in_start = ept.matrixTransform( eCTM ).matrixTransform( sCTM.inverse())
```

Now spt and ept_in_start have coordinates relative to the same element (the starting element) and in the same coordinate system (the SVG space of the starting element), and you can use those coordinates to draw anything you wish, based on the coordinates.

Of course, if the page reflows, you have to recalculate and redraw.  And you have to be sure to get the right CTM for the (x,y) coordinates of each endpoint... there are lots of overlaid coordinate systems if you have nested SVGs and transformations.